# How to format number using either jstl tags or numberFormat in scriptlet tags

Tags: java, jsp, scriptlet, jst

How to format number using either jstl tags or numberFormat in scriptlet tags?

I want to print the salary entered through form as:

```
Input?: 100000
Output: Rs 1,00,000
```

I've tried multiple things like:

```
Rs <%= NumberFormat("#,###,###").format(e.getSalary()) %>
```

but getting errors

Comment: what errors are you getting?

Comment: `<fmt:formatNumber pattern="#,##0.00" value="${number}"/>`

Comment: Don't use java in you jsp - Please, errors are hard to see and debugging is a pain.

Comment: Please see if this helps: https://www.javatpoint.com/jstl-fmt-formatnumber-tag